# Hibernate IS TRUE vs = TRUE

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jpql

I have a request in Hibernate that was working just fine in an older version of hibernate but after upgrading to a more recent one I have an error

> org.hibernate.query.SemanticException: A query exception occurred [SELECT count(c) FROM Client c WHERE c.tmp_batch IS TRUE]
> line 1:65 no viable alternative at input 'SELECTcount(c)FROMClientcWHEREc.tmp_batchISTRUE'

```java
public Long getClientCount() {
    return getEntityManager().createQuery("SELECT count(c) FROM Client c WHERE c.tmp_batch IS TRUE", Long.class)
        .getResultList()
        .get(0);
}
```

After testing a few things, I've got a solution for this problem that replace the `IS TRUE` by `= TRUE` and now it works fine again:

```java
public Long getClientCount() {
    return getEntityManager().createQuery("SELECT count(c) FROM Client c WHERE c.tmp_batch = TRUE", Long.class)
        .getResultList()
        .get(0);
}
```

But I'm unable to understand what's the difference between the two that make the first one to version fall in error, can someone explain the difference here ?

For reference, I'm adding the `Client` class here :

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "CLIENTS")
@IdClass(ClientId.class)
public class Client {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "TMP_BATCH")
    private boolean tmp_batch;

    ...

    public boolean isTmp_batch() { return this.tmp_batch; }
    public boolean setTmp_batch(boolean tmp_batch) { this.tmp_batch = tmp_batch; }

    ...

}
```

Comment: (mind you hibernate's queries are technically not just SQL, but the ideas do largely transfer). In particular from that linked question: "The IS comparison is only for null comparisons."

Comment: Thank you for the link, I wasn't able to find it, I get the idea